# How to pass data from parent to child blazor component

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, .net-6.0, mudblazor

Is there a way to pass data from input field of parent component to child component ?

I tried to make a parameter in parent and bind_value of textfield to the parameter and access the parameter in child component using renderfragment but it doesn't work [image]

Comment: Why don't you make input [Parameter] in the child component and just provide the value from parent to the child via that property? I don't see a reason having it in the parent.

Comment: Please add the code in your question as a text, not as a picture.

Comment: Here you can find link for the code : https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QaGcvPwxyEbtWfGU

Comment: @eduard : because i want to keep the parent component generic that i can used it in different components without modifying the parent component

Answer (score 1):

Get the value in the parent component from the input field like you do now and provide it to child component.

Parent.razor

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="@SearchString"/>
<MyChildComponent @bind-SearchValue="@SearchString"

@code {
   public string SearchString { get; set; }
}
```

MyChildComponent.razor

```
@code {
   [Parameter] public string SearchValue {get;set;}

   private string _searchValue;

   protected override void OnParametersSet()
   {
       if (_searchValue!= SearchValue)
       {
          _searchValue= SearchValue;
          OnSearchValueUpdate(); // whatever you want to do here
       }
   }
}
```